# Is there a way to set a GitHub issue number?

Tags: github

We have an external issue tracker that have used for years where say an issue number is currently #417064 but on GitHub the issue number is assigned automatically and might be currently #111.

The problem come when adding references from one issue to another where it might show #109 which is not as useful as if it said #416934.

Is there a way to assign the issue number rather than it being auto incremental?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Even GitHub's APIs [don't](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) provide [a way](https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/createissueinput/) to [set](https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/updateissueinput/) an issue's ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option.

At our company we use external issue tracker also and all of the connections between github pull-requests and internal issues are connected with links on github issue (1 ticket per 1 issue). So issues on github may be connected the same.

At external issue tracker you may have some APIs to make references (but reference on description is a good choice).

Btw, github issue mechanism is the same mechanism as any external issue tracker. It looks like that you may choose one issues tracker (not two or more) is much comfortable to manage processes represented in one issue tracker.